# Determine if parent has one or more children using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two models, **Purchase** and **Tag**.
 
A Purchase can have many Tags (One to Many relationship).

What is the **best** (Efficent/Cleanest/etc) way to return all purchases that have one or more tags? (The actual tag entities dont have to be returned).

I'm currently using a column in the purchase table to determine if it has been tagged but would like to remove it (See PurchaseDAO for it been used)

***PurchaseController***:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "purchases/tagged", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public final List<Purchase> getTagged()
{
    return RestPreconditions.checkNotNull(purchaseService.getTagged());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "purchases/pending", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public final List<Purchase> getPending()
{
    return RestPreconditions.checkNotNull(purchaseService.getPending());
}
```

***PurchaseService***:

```
@Service
public class PurchaseService implements IPurchaseService
{
    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseDAO purchaseDAO;

    public PurchaseService()
    {

    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Purchase> getAll()
    {
        return purchaseDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Purchase> getPending()
    {
        return purchaseDAO.getPending();
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Purchase> getTagged()
    {
        return purchaseDAO.getTagged();
    }
}
```

***PurchaseDAO***:

```
@Repository
public class PurchaseDAO extends AbstractJpaDAO<Purchase> implements IPurchaseDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public PurchaseDAO() {
        setClazz(Purchase.class);
    }

    public  List<Purchase> getPending() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Purchase where tagged = 0")
                .getResultList();
    }

    public  List<Purchase> getTagged() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Purchase where tagged = 1")
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Both my Purchase and Tag DAOs extend the following ***AbstractJpaDAO***:

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaDAO<T extends Serializable> implements
        IAbstractJpaDAO<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    public T findOne(final Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName())
                .getResultList();
    }

    public void save(final T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Thanks

### JB Suggestion Update

After changing PurchaseDAO getTagged() to:

```
public  List<Purchase> getTagged() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Puchase p INNER JOIN p.tags")
                .getResultList();
    }
```

I get following error:

```
TRACE [http-bio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:322] Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/PurchaseAPIServer/api/purchases/tagged]; client=[192.168.1.17]; method=[GET]; servlet=[PurchaseAPIServer]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[411ms]; status=[failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Puchase is not mapped [SELECT p FROM Puchase p JOIN p.tags tag]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Puchase is not mapped [SELECT p FROM Puchase p JOIN p.tags tag]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p from Purchase p inner join p.tags
```

The inner join just makes there is at least one tag for the purchase.

Comment: Thanks JB. I thought there might have been some non-sql way of achieving it.

Comment: And you thought well. The above is not SQL, but JPQL.

Comment: I get a Purchase not mapped error for this JPQL JB? See full error in original question update.

Comment: It was a typo in the query. I wrote `Puchase` instead of `Purchase`.

Comment: That is something I should have spotted! I need to go back to bed and get some sleep!